# AWS S3 API session expiration time

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm using golang to access an AWS S3 bucket to download files, the workflow of my API is very simple, it is just a cron that download a single file each day at certain time, my questions are:

It is mandatory to create the session on each execution of the cron?

How long will be available the session without expiration if I keep the same session for each call?

(I can't find it in the documentation)

I'm using [this portion of code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html#s3-examples-bucket-ops-download-file-from-bucket) to create the session and donwload the file:

```
sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
)

downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this case "session" is just configuration. There is no connection that is maintained, each method call is a new API call.

Comment: Is this on a cron job schedule or do you have a timer internal to the application?  If if is on a cron, it needs to be created on every invocation since the application exits and releases resources after execution.

Comment: @Justin have an internal timer in the API that runs the job every day

Comment: @Adrian great!  so.. I can create the session once at startup and then every time the API download the file will be using the same session instance/struct for each call ... Is that OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it has been established that you have a `time.Timer` for triggering the download.  Since this is the case, you only need to create a single session object and it can be re-used as many times as you want.  If you read the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/), you can find this line:

> Sessions should be cached when possible, because creating a new Session will load all configuration values from the environment, and config files each time the Session is created.